# Printing script intro by typing Y/y or just by pressing Enter in a POSIX shell script

Tags: shell, posix

Say, I have my POSIX script introduction stored in variable:

```sh
script_intro=\
'------------------------------------------------------------
--           Safe system files editing as root            --
--           Code language: POSIX shell script            --
--         Copyright: 2020-2023 Vlastimil Burian          --
--             Email: info@vlastimilburian.cz             --
--              GitHub: https://git.io/Jvnzq              --
--                 License: The Unlicense                 --
--                  Version 5.0 (stable)                  --
--                 Released: 2023-Feb-13                  --
------------------------------------------------------------'
```

This was actually made by `boxes` (`boxes -d ada-box -a c -s 60`).

---

And now say we have a function to ask if the user wants to display that intro and I want that done by default (<kbd>y</kbd>`*`/<kbd>Enter</kbd>), where the interesting part is the Enter key which was mostly attributed to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35468493/1997354).

```sh
sudoedit_help ()
{
    printf '%s' 'sudoedit-enhanced: Do you wish to print intro? [Y/Enter] / ? '
    IFS= read -r print_intro
    case "$print_intro" in
        ([Yy]*|'') printf '%s\n' "$script_intro"
    esac
    
    cat << EOF
Main useful info like usage...
Usage example: suvim /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2
EOF
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem #1

`sudoedit_help` or generally `sudoedit_whatever` functions will populate the shell and be *messing* with the standard `sudoedit` command in shell command completion for the user.

There is a simple solution to it, the best I came up with is prefixing the functions with an underscore like this:

```sh
_sudoedit_help ()
{
...
}
```

---

### Problem #2

Before asking any additional question(s), help should be displayed. Like this:

```sh
_sudoedit_help ()
{
    cat <<EOF
sudoedit-enhanced: Usage
Example: suvi /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2
EOF

...
}
```

---

### Problem #3 (cosmetic)

Sentence *sudoedit-enhanced: Do you wish to print intro? [Y/Enter] / ?* can be better phrased like this:

```
sudoedit-enhanced: Do you wish to print intro? [y/Enter/?]
```

---

### Problem #4

The function name could be named better, e.g. to contain a verb. Like this:

```sh
_sudoedit_show_help ()
{
...
}
```

---

### Problem #5

*sudoedit-enhanced: Usage* could really be better phrased. Like this: *Usage of sudoedit-enhanced shell extension*.

And since we are showing one single example of use, then `vim` shall be replaced by the basic `vi` to be more generic.

---

### Refactored code

```sh
_sudoedit_show_help ()
{
    cat <<EOF
Usage of sudoedit-enhanced shell extension:
Example: suvi /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2
EOF

    printf '\n%s' 'sudoedit-enhanced: Do you wish to print intro? [y/Enter/?] '
    IFS= read -r print_intro
    case "$print_intro" in
        ([Yy]*|'') printf '%s\n' "$script_intro"
    esac
}
```